# using a counter variable in Perl hash key names

Tags: perl, variables, hash

I've got a bunch of HTML form field data coming in as a hash, where each field name becomes the key & the field value is the hash value... your standard CGI module output from:

```
my $query = new CGI;
my %formdata = $query->Vars;
```

This time I'm working with a collection of multiple form fields that each have a numeric suffix ("name1" "name2" ... "size1" "size2" etc). Is there a better way to use a counter to loop through the group of those in numeric order than this?

```
for (my $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
  print "  Name $i: " . $formdata{"name$i"} . "\n";
  print "  Size $i: " . $formdata{"size$i"} . "\n";
}
```

...This isn't bad but is there a simpler syntax? I.e. like this (but this doesn't work - *Can't call method "name" without a package or object reference*):

```
  print "  Name $i: $formdata{name$i}\n";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious solution doesn't work:

```
  print "  Name $i: $formdata{"name$i"}\n";
```

but can be fixed by replacing either of the sets of actual double-quotes `"..."` with the `qq` operator (`qq{...}` or `qq(...)` or `qq/.../` or whatever-you-like):

```
  print qq{  Name $i: $formdata{"name$i"}\n};
```

See ["Quote and Quote-like Operators" in the `perlop` man-page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if there's another way since print "name $i $formdata{$varname}"; seems to work without the double interpolation when the _entire_ key name is made into a string variable...

Comment: @Wick: I think you're misunderstanding why `"$formdata{$varname}"` works. It actually *doesn't* interpolate `$varname`; it just takes `$varname` to be a normal string expression -- which it is -- and uses the value of that expression as the key. Note that you can write `$formdata{$varname}` even outside double-quotes; and conversely, you can write something like `$formdata{'name' . $i}` even inside double-quotes. Does that make sense? So `qq{$formdata{"name$i"}}` isn't doing "double interpolation"; it's interpolating `$i` exactly once, and interpolating e.g. `$formdata{'name6'}` exactly once.

Comment: Ah ha, thank you, that explains a ton & very clearly. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this sort of thing by making a list of keys based on the form name prefix. For example,

```
my @numbers = sort map { /name(\d+)/ } keys %formdata;
foreach my $num( @numbers ) { 
    print "  Name $num: ", $formdata{ 'name' . $num }, "\n";
    ...
}
```

This has the advantage of working for any number of form elements.

Comment: `sort`, by default, uses ASCIIbetical string comparison. You must mean `sort { $a <=> $b } map ...` rather than simply `sort map ...`. Also, I think you should anchor your regex to string-start and string-end, by writing `/^name(\d+)\z/` instead of `/name(\d+)/`.

Comment: Neat, seems like a good solid method for getting the max fields. Definitely an improvement on hard-coding the loop max in the script, just in case the form ever changes & someone forgets to update the script too. Not exactly what I was after but also very cool! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `"` in a string delimited by `"`, escape it.

```
print "  Name $i: $formdata{\"name$i\"}\n";
```

Or change the delimiter.

```
print qq{  Name $i: $formdata{"name$i"}\n};
```

Or avoid using `"`.

```
print "  Name $i: $formdata{qq{name$i}}\n";
print "  Name $i: $formdata{'name'.$i}\n";
printf "  Name %s: %s\n", $i, $formdata{"name$i"};
print "  Name $i: " . $formdata{"name$i"} . "\n";
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. ruakh got this in his answer & followup comments about an hour before yours came in, but otherwise I think your answer is definitely right on too & I appreciate all the examples. Have a good one